# nginx/memcached for cached web proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, http, memcached, http-proxy

I'm trying to setup nginx as a caching layer on top of an HTTP proxy - along with memcached to do the actual caching.  The goal here is that we have an internal application which will make frequent *outgoing* HTTP requests, and we want to use nginx+memcached as a web proxy to speed up the responses to these outgoing client requests.  (Especially since many requests may be redundant).

There's a lot of nice documentation and information on setting up nginx along with memcached out there, but I'm running into a problem because it seems like my particular use case isn't too common.  Most tutorials, examples, etc. assume the reader is *running a website*, and wants to use nginx+memcached to increase website performance.

But my use-case is different.  I just want to use nginx as a web caching proxy, and use memcached as the actual storage layer for caching.  Again, I'm not interested in speeding up performance for *incoming* requests to a website - I'm interested in speeding up *outgoing* HTTP requests from an internal app.

So, although there seems to be a lot of tutorials online which explain how to set up nginx as a [web cache proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/), as well as many tutorials online which explain how to setup nginx+memcached as a high-performance caching webserver, there doesn't seem to be much in the way of explaining how to setup nginx as a web cache proxy that uses memcached to do the actual caching.

Okay, so I've tried to read between the lines and figure it out myself.  I have nginx and memcached both installed locally on a dev box.  I'm also using the "[Enhanced Nginx Memcached Module](https://github.com/bpaquet/ngx_http_enhanced_memcached_module)", rather than the nginx+memcached module that comes with nginx out of the box, because apparently the out-of-the-box version [doesn't cache HTTP headers](http://blog.octo.com/en/http-caching-with-nginx-and-memcached/) (which would seem to make it unusable in practice, unless I'm missing something here).

So the relevant portion of my `nginx.conf` file is:

```
upstream some-upstream-proxy {
    server proxy.giant-corporation.com:82;
}

upstream memcached_upstream {
    server 127.0.0.1:11211;
    keepalive 20;
}

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name my-cache-proxy;

   location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://some-upstream-proxy;
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        set $enhanced_memcached_key "$request_uri";
        set $enhanced_memcached_key_namespace "$host";
        set $enhanced_memcached_use_add 1;
        set $enhanced_memcached_expire $http_memcached_expire;
        enhanced_memcached_hash_keys_with_md5 on;
        enhanced_memcached_pass memcached_upstream;

        error_page 404 = @fallback;
    }
}
```

So, my understanding here is that what this is supposed to do is the following:

1. An HTTP request is made to nginx.
2. Nginx looks up the URI in memcached.   If it finds the URI, it returns the cached response data.
3. If it *doesn't* find the URI, it falls back on `@fallback`    and uses the upstream HTTP proxy to make an HTTP request.
4. It then caches that request in `memcached` and returns the response to the client.

So my `nginx.conf` file seems to be *mostly* doing what I want, except for the last step.  It looks like it's adding in an entry for the URI, but the actual cached value appears to be 0 bytes.

For example, if I run nginx and memcached with the above `nginx.conf` file, and then I say:

```
 curl http://www.google.com/ --proxy http://localhost:80
```

... I get the actual response data from Google.  Then, if I check memcached stats, I see:

```
STAT cmd_get 21
STAT cmd_set 1
```

And after each request I see `cmd_get` is increasing.  But if I do an actual memcached dump, I see:

```
$ memcached-tool localhost:11211 dump
Dumping memcache contents
  Number of buckets: 1
  Number of items  : 1
Dumping bucket 1 - 1 total items
add __ns__www.google.com 0 1479132450 1
0
```

So I see that nginx is definitely communicating with `memcached`, and has successfully inserted the URI I requested.  But it doesn't appear to be actually caching the response it gets from the http proxy server.  It just has a 0 byte entry for `www.google.com`.

So... what step am I missing here? How can I modify my `nginx.conf` file to do what I want?

Comment: nginx was not designed to be a forward proxy, and will probably not have good performance even if you get this to work. Use a proper forward proxy such as squid.